# How long is a serial buffer in linux?

Tags: c, buffer, uart, tty, termios

My question regards `<termios.h>`. As I understand, two buffers exist in reading something over a UART - a hardware buffer where received bytes are stored, and a software buffer where we load the stuff that has been stored in the hardware buffer. This software buffer is the second argument in `read(uart_channel, BUFFER, length)` as I understand.

Please explain: how long is the hardware buffer? Do I have control over how long it is? For me it is critical to read the **12 most recent bytes sent over UART** by a device - how can I ensure this?

Comment: The buffer you provide to `read()` is your application's buffer, where any available serial data will be written. This is application-level, so it's not part of the driver's buffering of course. Actual hardware buffering (FIFO) will of course be hardware-dependent and you don't say what you're using. There's also an in-kernel buffer, I failed to figure out its size (and whether or not it's changable).

Comment: @unwind I am usinf a raspberry pi 1 model B+. Is there not way to clear the hardware buffer in termios?

Comment: Most uC I've seen have a hardwre FIFO that can be set to interrupt after, say [1,2,4,8,16] bytes.  If you really must have access to bytes ASAP, then you need to set the FIFO 'length' to 1. Of course, your driver should do that when initializing the UART.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation once and what I did is to create a thread that kept on reading the UART (blocking `read`) and I used a FIFO between the threads.

If you cannot use threading, you might just use `select`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify, I am using a Raspberry Pi 1 model B+. I actually do have a pthread that reads the uart, but it also does filtering and such so risks to read the uart only after it has already been filled up with more values. I am using a blocking read already (VTIME=0, VMIN=12). Is there a way to just clear the hardware buffer?

Comment: So do the filtering in the other thread. You can try `tcflush`, it should work.

Comment: @space_voyager *"I am using a blocking read already (VTIME=0, VMIN=12)"* -- That's a peculiar non-canonical mode that often leads to synchronization issues.  Very likely you are asking an XY question.  I.E you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Most uC I've seen have a hardware FIFO that can be set to interrupt after, say [1,2,4,8,16] bytes.  If the FIFO is left 'partially full' for some small multiple of the character interval for the currently configured baud rate, the UART interrupts anyway.  If you really must have access to bytes ASAP, then you need to set the FIFO 'length' to 1. Of course, your driver should do that when initializing the UART.

Failing that, I guess you could poll it:(